# Как сделать чтобы строки выводились в обратномй направлении

Tags: javascript, html

Как возвратить строку в обратной направлении. Например: строку hello на olleh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно решить задачу используя итеротивный процесс т.е через рекурсию

```js
const reverse = (str) =>{
    const iter = (counter, result) =>{
        if(str.length == result.length){
            return result;
        }        
        return iter(counter - 1, result + str[counter]);
    }
    return iter(str.length-1, ''); 
}
console.log('Reverse: ' + reverse('hello')); // olleh
```

Comment: Огооо спасииибооо! Работает. Ка то замудренно)

Comment: @FrontEnd покороче (и, возможно, попроще) рекурсивное решение может выглядеть так: `const reverse = str => str ? reverse(str.substr(1)) + str[0] : str;`

Answer (score 5):

Можно при помощи [`Array.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

```js
let reverse = a => a.split('') // разбиваем строку на массив символов
                    .reverse() // инвертируем порядок следования элементов в массиве
                    .join(''); // объединяем массив обратно в строку


console.log(reverse('hello'))
console.log(reverse('breakfast'))
```

Answer (score 2):

А можно - с помощью цикла:

```js
function reverse(str) {
  let result = '';
  for(let i = str.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    result += str[i];
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(reverse('hello'))
```

Answer (score 1):

то же самое, только с использованием `spread` оператора вместо `split`

```js
const str = 'hello';
console.log([...str].reverse().join(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы все на полном серьёзе?? А так не проще?

```js
let str = 'hello';
console.log(str.split('').reverse().join(''));
```

Comment: Вы точно прочитали Все ответы? Чем тогда Ваш ответ отличается от моего?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ когда писал, не видел. Ни чем. А что?